# what are the technologies for building real time applications using Node JS?

Tags: node.js, sockets, architecture, real-time, scalability

i tried to search for many topics because i am planning to build backed and API  for   real-time application like twitter  which has many users interactions , live comments and  sharing posts in home page like any social application

1. i just want what is the best Database type should i use
2. what is best architecture to build application like this
3. what topics should i read about
4. to handle sockets  i decided to use node js  ,  which nodejs framework will be suitable in this    case

Answer (score 1):

I think that the most robust and fleaibale  JS framework is Meteor

http://www.angular-meteor.com/

this frame work allow you to build scaleable apps with one code language all the way from client to DB .

i think that you should see the tutorials that walkthrough a demo app that is exactly what you describe, and there are some very great Git repos that build popular apps using this framework.

Regarding the servers and the scale factor , this is already an IT and automation issue that you need to solve.

for code deployment and frontend servers you can use autoscale techniques that can be found on AWS / GCE .
for DB selection you can use MongoDb that is quite popular or CouchDB . both can work with elastic search that will be the dashboard / stats tool that will show you what is going on.

i think that you will find meteor very easy to learn and build web applications.